# asp.net mvc3 / razor view best practices

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, view

I am using in my views `(asp mvc3/razor cshtml)` references to the Request object `(eg, @Request.Params["Name"])`. Do you think this is a very bad practice? Should I rewrite the value in the controller `Request.Params ["Name"]` to `ViewBag.Name` and then use it in the view `(@ViewBag.Name)`?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to use a model class. An instance of the model class is created or updated in your controller. Then the controller displays a strongly-typed view.

So I'd avoid direct access to the request from the view as well as the use of the view bag.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I rewrite the value in the controller Request.Params ["Name"] to ViewBag.Name and then use it in the view (@ViewBag.Name)?

**Yes.** You will avoid runtime errors if "Name" does not exist.

The IDE will not warn you of the `NullReferenceException` about to be thrown with the following code.

```
@Request.Params["Fake"].ToString()
```

Of course, you'll have to be careful about `ViewBag.Fake` being null as well.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the viewbag to store things not related to the model, for example if I have a dropdown containing locations. I like to store only the id of the selected location on the model and the locations in the viewbag, since is not needed to create a contact. I think that's the purpose of the viewbag.

For me the model is a bag or properties used in business operations, for example if I have a customer creation view using a `NewCustomerModel`, I don't wanna pollute my model with things like a `IList<CustomerType>` AND a `SelectedCustomerTypeId` property. I just want the second since is the one imma use to create the customer.